# Calculating the actual average value

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, estimation, average

I've got a relatively little (~100 values) set of integers: each of them represents how much time (in millisecond) a test I ran lasted.

The trivial algorithm to calculate the average is to sum up all the `n` values and divide the result by `n`, but this doesn't take into account that some ridiculously high/low value must be wrong and should get discarded.

What algorithms are available to estimate the actual average value?

Comment: There is no such thing as the "actual" average value: You cannot strictly distinguish statistical outliers from actual data without making some assumptions. What constitutes actual data and what's error is ultimately a probabilistic decision. Also, this isn't strictly a programming question, but one about statistics.

Comment: +1 stakx. Also, I might suggest that the assumption that 'ridiculous' values are 'wrong' may be incorrect. I would suggest just running more tests (1000 or 10000) and taking the *mean* value as-is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said you can discard all values that diverge more than a given value from the average and then recompute the average. Another value that can be interesting is the Median, that is the most frequent value.

Comment: Mode is the most frequent value (or values).

Comment: @peoro, yes there is but it's not so easy. Look for Standard Deviation

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation

there are several math library with that

Comment: For every set of data could make sense to discard values with Sigma (the absolute deviation) higher than a given number, but it depends by the event type. There is no one-fit-all solution.

Comment: @Uberto - even your link describes Median as "median is described as the numeric value separating the higher half of a sample, a population, or a probability distribution, from the lower half." It is the middle value (and given its name, that makes sense). From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics): "mode is the value that occurs the most frequently in a data set or a probability distribution."

Answer (score 1):

It depends on different conditions of your test. And it is a task from probability theory.
One of the simplest way is to try calculate a **median**, that you can deal with ridiculously high/low values. Look at link below:
[Wiki about median](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median)

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, the arithmetic mean isn't good if there are very high/low values.
You could compute the median, as someone suggested, which is, in a sorted list of your values, the "middle" value (if your set contains an uneven amount of items) or the arithmetic mean of the two "middle" values (else).

Another method would be to drop, say, the lowest and highest five [percentiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile) and compute the arithmetic mean of the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Some options:

- First discard N highest and lowest values and compute arithmetic mean for the rest. Set N to suitable value so that, for example 1% or 10% of values are discarded.
- Use the  the [median](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median), or middle value.
- Use [geometric mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean) that give less weight for the outliers.

Wikipedia lists [some ways](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean) to compute different "mean" values